# How can I downgrade packaging when installing scanpy?

Tags: python, packaging, scanpy

When trying to install scanpy, I get the following error

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
poetry 1.1.11 requires packaging<21.0,>=20.4, but you have packaging 21.2 which is incompatible
```

In that sense, I tried to downgrade packaging from version 21.2 to 20.9 or 20.8, with

```
! pip install --upgrade packaging==20.9
```

or with

```
! pip uninstall packaging -y
! pip install -I packaging==20.8
```

but I still get that error, as if the packaging version did not change.

Here is the full block

```
! pip install --upgrade packaging==20.9
#! pip uninstall packaging -y
#! pip install -I packaging==20.8
#! pip install poetry --upgrade
! pip uninstall scanpy -y
! pip install -I scanpy
```

and the full output

```
Collecting packaging==20.9
  Using cached packaging-20.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in /data04/projects04/MarianaBoroni/lbbc_members/lib/conda_envs/diogoamb/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from packaging==20.9) (3.0.4)
Installing collected packages: packaging
  Attempting uninstall: packaging
    Found existing installation: packaging 21.2
    Uninstalling packaging-21.2:
      Successfully uninstalled packaging-21.2
Successfully installed packaging-20.9
Found existing installation: scanpy 1.8.2
Uninstalling scanpy-1.8.2:
  Successfully uninstalled scanpy-1.8.2
Collecting scanpy
  Using cached scanpy-1.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.0 MB)
Collecting anndata>=0.7.4
  Using cached anndata-0.7.6-py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
Collecting h5py>=2.10.0
  Using cached h5py-3.5.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (4.5 MB)
Collecting scipy>=1.4
  Using cached scipy-1.7.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (28.5 MB)
Collecting sinfo
  Using cached sinfo-0.3.4-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting matplotlib>=3.1.2
  Using cached matplotlib-3.4.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.3 MB)
Collecting umap-learn>=0.3.10
  Using cached umap_learn-0.5.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numba>=0.41.0
  Using cached numba-0.54.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.whl (3.3 MB)
Collecting joblib
  Using cached joblib-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (306 kB)
Collecting numpy>=1.17.0
  Using cached numpy-1.21.4-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (15.7 MB)
Collecting seaborn
  Using cached seaborn-0.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (292 kB)
Collecting natsort
  Using cached natsort-8.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting statsmodels>=0.10.0rc2
  Using cached statsmodels-0.13.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (9.9 MB)
Collecting networkx>=2.3
  Using cached networkx-2.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.9 MB)
Collecting tables
  Using cached tables-3.6.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (14.3 MB)
Collecting tqdm
  Using cached tqdm-4.62.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
Collecting patsy
  Using cached patsy-0.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (233 kB)
Collecting scikit-learn>=0.22
  Using cached scikit_learn-1.0.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (24.7 MB)
Collecting packaging
  Using cached packaging-21.2-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting pandas>=0.21
  Using cached pandas-1.3.4-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.5 MB)
Collecting xlrd<2.0
  Using cached xlrd-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (103 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.3.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.6 MB)
Collecting cycler>=0.10
  Using cached cycler-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.2.1
  Using cached pyparsing-3.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.7
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting pillow>=6.2.0
  Using cached Pillow-8.4.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.1 MB)
Collecting llvmlite<0.38,>=0.37.0rc1
  Using cached llvmlite-0.37.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (26.3 MB)
Collecting numpy>=1.17.0
  Using cached numpy-1.20.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (15.4 MB)
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-58.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (946 kB)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.2.1
  Using cached pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting pytz>=2017.3
  Using cached pytz-2021.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (503 kB)
Collecting six>=1.5
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting threadpoolctl>=2.0.0
  Using cached threadpoolctl-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting pynndescent>=0.5
  Using cached pynndescent-0.5.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting stdlib-list
  Using cached stdlib_list-0.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
Collecting numexpr>=2.6.2
  Using cached numexpr-2.7.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (471 kB)
Installing collected packages: numpy, threadpoolctl, six, setuptools, scipy, llvmlite, joblib, scikit-learn, pytz, python-dateutil, pyparsing, pillow, numba, kiwisolver, cycler, xlrd, tqdm, stdlib-list, pynndescent, patsy, pandas, packaging, numexpr, natsort, matplotlib, h5py, umap-learn, tables, statsmodels, sinfo, seaborn, networkx, anndata, scanpy
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
poetry 1.1.11 requires packaging<21.0,>=20.4, but you have packaging 21.2 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed anndata-0.7.6 cycler-0.11.0 h5py-3.5.0 joblib-1.1.0 kiwisolver-1.3.2 llvmlite-0.37.0 matplotlib-3.4.3 natsort-8.0.0 networkx-2.6.3 numba-0.54.1 numexpr-2.7.3 numpy-1.21.1 packaging-21.2 pandas-1.3.4 patsy-0.5.2 pillow-8.4.0 pynndescent-0.5.5 pyparsing-3.0.4 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pytz-2021.3 scanpy-1.8.2 scikit-learn-1.0.1 scipy-1.7.1 seaborn-0.11.2 setuptools-58.5.3 sinfo-0.3.4 six-1.16.0 statsmodels-0.13.0 stdlib-list-0.8.0 tables-3.6.1 threadpoolctl-3.0.0 tqdm-4.62.3 umap-learn-0.5.2 xlrd-1.2.0
```

Comment: You should use a package manager like conda or mamba, it will help you to resolve conflicts like that

Comment: hi Gino. I am using conda in jupyter notebook

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing all your packages in one line like this and see if the conflicts are resolved, `pip install packaging scanpy`. You could also try with your specific versions like this `pip install packaging==20.9 scanpy==1.0` or whatever version you like. You can also try installing like this `pip install package>=20.9 package2<1.9`

You could also try using a package manager like conda or mamba, create a new environment and try installing the packages there. The package managers try to resolve conflicts like that.

Comment: Thank you anarchy. I am already using conda. Should I create a new environment still?

Comment: Yes you should never use the base environment @DiogodeMoraes